How should components be delivered differently to mobile apps vs web browsers in a headless Sitecore Layout Service setup?
I need to implement different component delivery for mobile apps and web browsers in my Next.js application using Headless Sitecore 10.3's Layout Service.
Currently, I have 4 components configured in the Default layout:
Mobile apps should receive all 4 components
Web browsers should only receive 2 components
However, when using the Layout Service, all 4 components are being delivered to both platforms.
Is there a way to configure Sitecore's Layout Service to deliver different components based on the platform (mobile vs. web) in a headless implementation?

Yes, There is one option in Sitecore for this  you need to  add Devices type in Layout Section. As shown in Screenshot I 'have added  new Device type Mobile which we can use for Mobile components.

In the Presentation Details section, you can customize layouts and components for different platforms. The default section allows you to configure specific layouts and components for the web interface,
while the newly created Mobile section lets you customize layouts and components for the mobile app. See the screenshot below for reference.

This is default layout service URL
/sitecore/api/layout/render/[config]?item=[path]&sc_lang=[language]&sc_apikey=[key]&tracking=[true|false]&sc_site=[your-site-name] 

Here you need to pass sc_device="mobile" for Mobile components.
This enables platform-specific component delivery (mobile or web) within a headless architecture.
Hope this help!!

For this approach we need to create different layout for both mobile and web and same will work?

Hello Vaishali - you can use same layout. Please try with same and let me know if there is any issue.

if you are using Experience Edge, this method will not work.

Thanks Praveen, This was worked for me.
